# Как использовать offset совместно с paged?

Tags: php, wordpress

Если их вместе использовать, то пагинация не работает, а мне надо вывести все записи, кроме самой последней добавленной.

```
    $arr = [
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'cat' => 37,
    'paged' => 2,
    'offset' => 1


  ];

   $recent = new WP_Query($arr);
```

Нашёл решение на wp-kama, там он добавляет код в functions.php, но он мне не подходит.

Comment: Вв это решение имеет ввиду? https://wp-kama.ru/id_2647/kak-ispolzovat-parametr-offset-ne-lomaya-paginatsiyu.html и чем оно вам не подходит?

Comment: вообще не работает

Comment: Чушь не рассказывайте тут. У него обычно все работает. Давайте-ка выкладывайте ваш код, рассказывайте, куда его вставляли, давайте информацию о сайте и плагинах. Пока голосую за закрытие вопроса.

Comment: я сделал свой пагинатор